# Proposition 9.5 of Bott-Tu book

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms

In this proposition the homotopy operator
$L: C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)\rightarrow C^*(\mathfrak U,\Omega^*)$,
\begin{equation}
L\alpha = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}(L\alpha)_p,\;\;
(L\alpha)_p = \sum_{i=p+1}^{n}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\alpha_i\;\in C^p(\mathfrak U,\Omega^{n-(p+1)})
\end{equation}
is defined.

For $\alpha = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_i$ and $D\alpha = \beta = \sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\beta_i$,
we define
\begin{equation}
f(\alpha) := \sum_{i=0}^{n}(-D''K)^i\alpha_i
 - \sum_{i=0}^{n}K(-D''K)^i\beta_{i+1}\;\in C^0(\mathfrak U,\Omega^n).
\end{equation}

The exercise to confirm the relation
$1-r\circ f = DL + LD$ is left to the readers.
How can we prove it?

The following is my procedure.
I think I have almost done but still have minor mistakes.
Please check..

\begin{align*}
DL(\alpha) + LD(\alpha)
&= (\delta+D'')\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\alpha_i + L\beta\\
&= \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\alpha_i 
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}K\delta(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\alpha_i\\
&\qquad
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}(-D''K)^{i-p}\alpha_i 
 + \sum_{p=0}^{n}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n+1}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\beta_i\\
&= \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\alpha_i 
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\delta\alpha_i
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+2)}D''\alpha_i\\
&\qquad
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}(-D''K)^{i-p}\alpha_i 
 + \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n+1}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\beta_i\\
&= \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\alpha_i 
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}(-D''\alpha_{i+1}+\beta_{i+1})
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+2)}D''\alpha_i\\
&\qquad
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}(-D''K)^{i-p}\alpha_i 
 + \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n+1}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\beta_i\\
&= \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\alpha_i 
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+2}^{n+1}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+2)}(-D''\alpha_i+\beta_i)
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+2)}D''\alpha_i\\
&\qquad
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}(-D''K)^{i-p}\alpha_i 
 + \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n+1}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\beta_i\\
&= \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\alpha_i 
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\beta_{i+1}\\
&\qquad
 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p+1}^{n}(-D''K)^{i-p}\alpha_i 
 + \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=p}^{n}K(-D''K)^{i-p}\beta_{i+1}.
\end{align*}
Changing of the ordering of the sum gives for $\alpha_i$ parts,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{p=0}^{i-1}(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\alpha_i
 - \sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{p=0}^{i-1}(-D''K)^{i-p}\alpha_i
= \sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{p=1}^{i}(-D''K)^{i-p}\alpha_i
 - \sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{p=0}^{i-1}(-D''K)^{i-p}\alpha_i
= \sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_i
 - \sum_{i=0}^{n}(-D''K)^i\alpha_i.
\end{equation*}
For $\beta_i$ parts,
\begin{align*}
-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{p=0}^{i-1}K(-D''K)^{i-(p+1)}\beta_{i+1}
 + \sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{p=0}^{i}K(-D''K)^{i-p}\beta_{i+1}
&= -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{p=1}^{i}K(-D''K)^{i-p}\beta_{i+1}
 + \sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{p=0}^{i}K(-D''K)^{i-p}\beta_{i+1}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n}K(-D''K)^i\beta_{i+1}.
\end{align*}
By adding them,
\begin{equation}
(DL+LD)(\alpha)
= \alpha - r\circ f(\alpha).
\end{equation}

Comment: LOL to "Please check." Not me!